# using in_aray function and show the different value from array of two value

Tags: php

Array of two element, how to test values and echo the different one using `in_array()`?

```
$b = "Mac";
$os = array($c, "Linux");
if (in_array($b, $os)) {
    //if($b==$c); want to echo Linux as out value 
}
```

I don't like to have a long code with and or ....

Any idea?

Comment: in_array not for checking different but to check if value exist in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$a = 'a';
$arr = ['a','b'];

if(in_array($a, $arr)) echo current(array_diff($arr, [$a])); //  --> b;
```

[**Live Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88bfe7c6f5ab7f8bcec7ace71722faba2662f210)

Comment: thanks it's exactelly what i search for . a simple code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)()

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to remove every entry that matches the search value.

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "Linux");
$search = "Mac"
foreach (array_keys($os, $search, true) as $key) {
    unset($messages[$key]);
}
foreach ($os as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
?>
```

---

You don't need to use in_array to do that if your array have only 2 values. Two if statements will resolve your problem.

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "Linux");
$search = "Mac"
if ($search === $os[0]) //Compare 1st position 
{ 
     echo $os[1]; //Print the opposite one
}
else if ($search === $os[1]) //Same with 2nd position
{
    echo $os[0];
}
else
{
    echo "Not Found";
}
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Comment: problem with $os = array("Mac", "Mac"); and search is Mac it's show Mac

Comment: In the opposite case, if you search Linux in array mac mac it should print mac mac, only mac or nothing?